# Read access violation when attempting strcpy from file buffer to char array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, char, strcpy

I've been working on an assignment to implement hashing. In it, I read through a text file called "proteins". The problem occurs when I try to copy it to another char array.  Visual Studio throws a read access violation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct arrayelement {
  char protein[30];
  int count;
}; 
arrayelement proteins[40];
int main()
{
  char buffer[30];

  // open source file
  ifstream fin("proteins.txt");
  if (!fin) { cerr << "Input file could not be opened\n"; exit(1); }

  // loop through strings in file
  while (fin >> buffer) {
    int index = ((buffer[0] - 65) + (2 * (buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] - 65)) % 40);
    while (true)
    {
        if (proteins[index].protein == buffer)  // Found
        {
            proteins[index].count++;
            break;
        }
        if (proteins[index].protein[0] == 0)    // Empty
        {
            strcpy(proteins[index].protein, buffer); // <-- The error in question
            proteins[index].count++;
            break;
        }
        index++;                                // Collision
     }
  }

  // close file
  fin.close();


  for (int i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
  {
    cout << proteins[i].protein << "\t" << proteins[i].count << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debug this? index may be at 40 when the error occurs.

Comment: Also use `std::string` and a `std::vector<arrayelement>`.

Comment: `proteins[index].protein == buffer` This is not how you want to compare char arrays.

Comment: @0x5453 Oh man, I'm too tired. That did it. After changing that to a strcmp it all runs. Thank you!

Comment: @Noctimor Because you are trying to do C when you are in C++. Use containers....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get more than 30 chars here:

```
while (fin >> buffer) {
```

... or if index >= 40 here:

```
strcpy(proteins[index].protein, buffer);
```

... the program will probably crash (Undefined behavior). Also, these `char*`'s will not be pointing at the same address, so the comparison will fail:

```
proteins[index].protein == buffer
```

Comment: Yep, it was the comparison that did me in. After rewriting it, everything runs. 

Part of the code here is given per the assignment -- the examples we're working with are guaranteed not to be above 30, and the index given is double what's needed, to practice collision resolution. Otherwise I'd absolutely clean that stuff up too. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Note: The index formula will result in 91 if the input string is `"z"`.
It'll become: `index = 57 + 114 % 40` => `57 + (114 % 40)`